# Add property path to custom validation in Micronaut

Tags: kotlin, micronaut

Given the below, working validator factory, is it possible somehow to manipulate propertyPath? When debugging, I can see propertyPath inside `io.micronaut.validation.validator.DefaultValidator$DefaultConstraintValidatorContext`.

Motivation for doing so, is that some fields are conditionally required, and I need to put validation annotation on class-level, but then propertyPath is set to class, not to the actual fields with validation errors. When returning validation errors to API-clients, it would be nice to have correct property name for validation errors.

```
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Factory
import io.micronaut.validation.validator.constraints.ConstraintValidator
import jakarta.inject.Singleton
import no.mycompany.myapp.web.config.UiConfig
import no.mycompany.myapp.web.viewmodel.MyExampleFormVm

@Factory
class ExampleValidatorFactory(private val uiConfig: UiConfig) {

    @Singleton
    fun validForm(): ConstraintValidator<ValidForm, MyExampleFormVm> = ConstraintValidator { value, _, context ->

        val formTypeFromConfig = uiConfig.formTypes.first { it.id == value.formType }

        if (formTypeFromConfig.labelSubCompanyId != null && value.subCompanyId == null) {
            context.messageTemplate("Form requires one or more sub-company-ids")
            // TODO: set propertyPath to "subCompanyId"
            return@ConstraintValidator false
        }

        if (formTypeFromConfig.labelCompanyId != null && value.companyId == null) {
            context.messageTemplate("Form requires company-id")
            // TODO: set propertyPath to "companyId"
            return@ConstraintValidator false
        }

        true
    }
}
```

Annotation

```
import javax.validation.Constraint

@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = [])
annotation class ValidForm(
    val message: String = "Invalid form ({validatedValue})"
)
```

Example bean to validate:

```
import io.micronaut.core.annotation.Introspected
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern

@Introspected
@ValidForm
data class MyExampleFormVm(

    @field:NotBlank
    val formType: String = "",

    @field:Pattern(regexp = "[8|9]\\d{8}")
    val companyId: String? = null,

    @field:Pattern(regexp = "[8|9]\\d{8}")
    val subCompanyId: String? = null
)
```

This is my custom `ConstraintExceptionHandler`. I want `it.propertyPath.lastOrNull()?.name` to return e.g. "subCompanyId".

```
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Replaces
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Requires
import io.micronaut.http.HttpRequest
import io.micronaut.http.HttpResponse
import io.micronaut.http.HttpStatus
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Produces
import io.micronaut.http.server.exceptions.response.ErrorResponseProcessor
import io.micronaut.validation.exceptions.ConstraintExceptionHandler
import jakarta.inject.Singleton
import java.time.Instant
import java.util.*
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException

@Produces
@Singleton
@Replaces(ConstraintExceptionHandler::class)
@Requires(classes = [ConstraintViolationException::class, ConstraintExceptionHandler::class])
class CustomConstraintExceptionHandler(responseProcessor: ErrorResponseProcessor<*>) :
    ConstraintExceptionHandler(responseProcessor) {

    override fun handle(request: HttpRequest<*>, exception: ConstraintViolationException): HttpResponse<*> =
        HttpResponse.badRequest(
            ApiError(
                timestamp = Instant.now().toEpochMilli(),
                httpStatusCode = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.code,
                errorType = ApiErrorType.VALIDATION_ERROR,
                url = request.path,
                validationErrors = exception.constraintViolations
                    .associate { (it.propertyPath.lastOrNull()?.name ?: FALLBACK_PROPERTY_PATH) to it.message }
            ))

    companion object {
        const val FALLBACK_PROPERTY_PATH = "ROOT"
    }
}

---

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude
import io.micronaut.core.annotation.Introspected

@Introspected
@JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
data class ApiError(
    val timestamp: Long,
    val httpStatusCode: Int,
    val errorType: ApiErrorType,
    val url: String,
    val validationErrors: Map<String, String>? = null
)

enum class ApiErrorType {
    VALIDATION_ERROR,
    SYSTEM_ERROR;
}
```

Question from @Bonatti

> If it.propertyPath.lastOrNull() is null, on the Handler, then that is
> weird.

If you do like this, `resultMap` will contain an entry with key="ROOT".

```
val exampleForm = MyExampleFormVm(
    formType = "SomeValue",
    companyId = "912345678",
    subCompanyId = null
)
val constraintViolations: Set<ConstraintViolation<MyExampleFormVm>> = validator.validate(exampleForm)
val resultMap = constraintViolations.associate { (it.propertyPath.lastOrNull()?.name ?: "ROOT") to it.message }
```

Environment: Micronaut 3.7.4

Comment: When you say `propertyPath´ are you using some context information (say from application.yaml), or are you referring to the complete name such as package.domain.MyExampleEtc)? I am having a hard time understanding the question, but I am willing to help. What do you expect? What actually happens? What errors/stack do you have? Is your validation actually being executed?

Comment: Hi @Bonatti. Sorry if question is kind of unclear. I'm referring to javax.validation.ConstraintViolation<T>#getPropertyPath which returns an instance of javax.validation.Path. Hence, I want constraintViolation.propertyPath.last().name to return e.g. "subCompanyId". 
"What actually happens?": Described in second paragraph in question. "What errors/stack do you have?": As I wrote in the question, the code is working. "Is your validation actually being executed?" Yes. I added my error handling code to the question. BR

Comment: Can you post the `MyExampleFormVm` or a mock of it? Suppose a `@field:NotNull`  on a field, then using a validator, you are expected to receive the `ConstraintViolationException` that you are overriding the default handler, in it, you also receive the original `request`. If `it.propertyPath.lastOrNull()` is null, on the Handler, then that is weird. If its `package.to.class` then its the expected behavior. I dont believe you can change the values on an item in the stacktrace. There are no setters in `javax.validation.ConstraintViolation` but, you could use reflection (bypasses Kotlin)

Comment: Hi @Bonatti: I added ExampleFormVm to my question. Please also see new section "Question from @Bonatti". BR

Comment: Ok, so I think I understand part of your question now. I suggest you debug the application, and put a breaking point on your Handler, so that you can access the Set of ConstraintViolations. In it, check the propertyPath (Path) that you have, and then access its Leaf(s) or Node(s), Name, and other properties, so that you can access what you want. If your entire Path is only "ROOT", then please post a screenshot of the debug session (with the Path), or use a System.out.println(path.toString()). Each ConstraintViolation should have: `package.to.class.field` as Path

Comment: Thanks for your efforts @Bonatti. I know that when the bean is validated by e.g. a controller method, `propertyPath.lastOrNull()` is not null, and when validation is run explicit as I showed you in my question, it will be null. However, I believe this is a sidetrack, because any validation errors added in my `validForm` validator will be added to the bean level context, not `companyId` nor `subCompanyId` as it will if any field-level validation is triggered. BR

Comment: Thats what I mean, you are adding the "ROOT", here: `it.propertyPath.lastOrNull()?.name ?: "ROOT"` . What I want you to validate is that the `Path` object you are receiving, should be complete and correct. Forget your mapping, check the Exception object. The `ConstraintViolation`.`getPropertyPath()` (Java), or `ConstraintViolation`.`propertyPath` (Kotlin), will give you the same correct result. In this Path, you can traverse it, to the correct expected field name.

Comment: To make this more visible, post a debug result, of the received ConstraintViolation (and the set of violations `constraintViolations`)

Comment: @Bonatti: Added screenshot from debug session. You're also welcome to debug your self, this is part of an open source repo found here: https://github.com/statisticsnorway/kostra-kontrollprogram

Please go to web module and `ApiControllerIntegrationTest`. If you focus on test on line 141 and set a breakpoint in `ValidatorFactory`, you'll get what I just posted. Parts of the doc is in Norwegian, sorry for that. BR

Comment: In the debug session, you have not posted exception, also, from documentation on `@Pattern` -> `The annotated CharSequence must match the specified regular expression. The regular expression follows the Java regular expression conventions see java.util.regex.Pattern.` and then: `Accepts CharSequence. null elements are considered valid.` Thats what I meant that the validation is not working, and to debug. Forget the associate for now, and focus on the Exception Object.

Comment: What happens on: `val exampleForm = MyExampleFormVm(formType = "SomeValue", companyId = "912345678", subCompanyId = "012345678")`

Comment: @Bonatti: "Thats what I meant that the validation is not working, and to debug. ". Controller integration tests says that validation rules are working just fine, all cases are covered :-)